# Using Ghostscript in Automator?

Tags: macos, ghostscript, automator

I'm a bit of a noob in automator, I hope this isn't a silly question.

I have a shell script `compdf.sh` that takes a pdf as input, flattens and compresses it, and saves it as a new file in the same directory with the suffix '_comp.pdf':

```
#!/bin/sh

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=‘.’
arr=($1)

prefix=${arr[0]}
suffix='_comp.pdf'
fout=$prefix$suffix
echo "Compressed file to be saved as $fout"

IFS=$OIFS

/usr/local/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
   -sOutputFile="$fout" "$1"
```

This script works like a charm in terminal, by issuing the command `compdf.sh <input_file>`. I want to turn it into a service using automator, but when run it issues an error (simply says "action failed" in the "Run Shell Script" box:

[image: Screen shot of workflow]

(*Note: I've added "Get Specified Finder Items" so I can see the results in Automator.) Clearly I'm not passing the input to the script properly, yet [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20131018214926/http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2010/05/07/passing-multiple-automator-variables-to-a-shell-script/) says inputs are passed as `$1-$n`. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script requires that you specify the input --> "**$@**"

```
/usr/local/bin/compdf.sh "$@"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works now.